# Github: How can I reply to several comments in one go

Tags: github, comments, review

Im my PR I received several comments on my code. In the conversation tab I see the comments underneath a green box with proposed changes and a space to reply to the comment. This is shown for each comment. I then can write my answer and click "Comment"

When I reply to those comments:  How can I answer to several comments **in one go** to prevent the reviewer getting a notification for *each* answer to his comments.

Answer (score 1):

This is the trick I use: go to the `Files Changed` tab, scroll down until you find the comments (optionally you can use the `Conversations` dropdown to select a comment), start replying to a comment and then click on `Start a review`. Now you can answer to more comments. Once you finish click on `Finish your review` and your teammates will get a single e-mail with all the comments inside.